# firebase cloud functions not working properly

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a hello world cloud functions function with firebase, and it is driving me up the wall that I can't make it work.  I am trying to use express,  and when I send a get request to http://localhost:5000/helloworld I get nothing back.  Can someone please take a look at my code and let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!   I am serving locally with firebase serve.  The console says "emulator started at http://localhost:5000."  Here is my code in the index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var express = require('express');
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never exported a function declaration and attached your Express app to it.  I suggest taking another look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) - you need to do something like this:

```
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Thanks @Doug Stevenson!  It was driving me up the wall I just figured it out.